# Why theses both egrep search don’t return the same result?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, grep, include-path

I’d like to understand why with the include parameter it doesn’t search into the file identification.php that were targeted.

---

With the **include** parameter :

```
admin@server:/filer/www/website/httpdocs$ egrep -Rns --include=*.php "deleteTemp" *
identification.php-sed:61:  $deleteTemp = " DELETE FROM ".$table_name."
identification.php-sed:64:  $execTemp   = @mysql_query ( $deleteTemp );
```

And without :

```
admin@server:/filer/www/website/httpdocs$ egrep -Rns "deleteTemp" *
identification.php:61:  $deleteTemp = " DELETE FROM ".$table_name."
identification.php:64:  $execTemp   = @mysql_query ( $deleteTemp );
identification.php-sed:61:  $deleteTemp = " DELETE FROM ".$table_name."
identification.php-sed:64:  $execTemp   = @mysql_query ( $deleteTemp );
```

I also tried with quotes for the pattern of the include and the result is the same.

Comment: Are you sure that first one returns entries from the `.php-sed` file? I would have expected it to return the results from the `.php` file and **not** the `.php-sed` file. Since `identification.php-sed` doesn't match the `*.php` pattern/glob.

Comment: Yes I’m sure, it’s for that I’m surprised, the inverse should be more logical…
However I would post on Superuser site but I fail :D

Comment: The most strange is with the dot wildcard at the end of the first request it result the opposite !

Comment: Weird, I did a test and with `--include=*.php` I am getting just the `*.php` files that match. May be good to indicate what `grep` version you are using.

Comment: My version : grep (GNU grep) 2.10 on a Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

I think it is because your pattern is being interpreted by the shell, try:

```
egrep -Rns --include=\*.php "deleteTemp" *
```

By the way, do you know [`ag`](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher)?

Comment: No. The shell leaves the `--include=\*.php` as-is, since there is no file matching `--include=\*.php`.

Comment: Yes it’s strictly the same I’d ever tried.
I just read about ack searching my response here but I can’t install anything on this machine.

Comment: I make a copy of identification.php and rename it identification2.php.foo and search with the same include found into this new file…

Comment: Searching from the parent folder and targeting the folder display the correct result also :
    admin@server:/filer/www/website$ egrep -Rns --include=*.php "deleteTemp" httpdocs
    httpdocs/identification.php:61:  $deleteTemp = " DELETE FROM ".$table_name."
    httpdocs/identification.php:64:  $execTemp   = @mysql_query ( $deleteTemp );

Comment: Guys, it works nice in all files with simply omit the * mark !

`egrep -Rn --include=.php 'deleteTemp' *`